# WorkManager v1 and v2 conflict

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager

I use **version 2 of WorkManager** that is in the **androidX** package.

I also use **another library which uses v1 of WorkManager** which is in the **Arch component** package.

When I sync the project, sync finishes successfully, but when I try to build the project. I get the following error that says you have duplicate values.

Version I use in **my Gradle**:
`"androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.0.1"`

Version added to the **library**:
`'android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:1.0.1'`

The **error**:

```
Duplicate class androidx.work.ArrayCreatingInputMerger found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-rc01) and classes.jar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1)
Duplicate class androidx.work.BackoffPolicy found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-rc01) and classes.jar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1)
Duplicate class androidx.work.Configuration found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-rc01) and classes.jar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1)
Duplicate class androidx.work.Configuration$Builder found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-rc01) and classes.jar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1)
...
```

I also have added these to my `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Can you consider requesting the library's author to update their library to support the AndroidX version of WorkManager?

Comment: I guess this would be the last solution. Any other workarounds?

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think there's any other way to bypass this problem.

Comment: why there are no `build.gradle` dependencies? this should be easy to answer.

Comment: What informations do you need?

Comment: if you'd expect an answer, don't just provide the error messages, but the `dependencies` block which produces them (you may remove some of them, but it still has to produce the same error).

Comment: Have you tried excluding the work manager while implementing library? Something similar to `implementation project(':your_library'){ exclude group :'android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx' }`
*This is not tested. Do let me know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases where you don't want a dependency from a third party library, you can simply **exclude** it out of that library.

In your case, you can exclude `android.arch` work manager and add your own `androidX` work manager instead.

Something similar to:

```
implementation('your_library') { 
    exclude group :'android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is because of the two workmanager dependencies. Try removing the second one i.e. `android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:1.0.1`. And migrate your code with respect to the `androidx` version

Comment: That's the problem. Version 1 is used by the library and I don't have access to modify this.